# getElementById().click() not running in if statement scope

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, login-script

I'm trying to run the following code If statement runs with `console.log()` alone and `getElementById.click()` on its own. But not when combined. I'm trying to redirect a page on my web app in google apps script.

```
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", submitL); //eventlistener for login 
function submitL() {
  var loginInfo = {}
  loginInfo.email = document.getElementById.("email").value;
  loginInfo.password = document.getElementById.("password").value;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15rUIxS8w53bvPZvTKuOdGw-ZP6eWMaykVJ26vqGBkEg");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("logindet");
  var loginList = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  var email = loginList.map(function (r) {
    return r[0]
  });

  var password = loginList.map(function (r) {
    return r[1]
  });

  var viewNameData = loginList.map(function (r) {
    return r[2]
  });
  var loginEmail = loginInfo.email;
  var loginPW = loginInfo.password;
  for (var i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
    if ((loginEmail == email[i]) && (loginPW == password[i])) {
      document.getElementById("load").click();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById()` can only be called in your client-side code. `SpreadsheetApp` can only be called  in your backend code. Please review [client-to-server communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: From the https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361 `click
Simulate a mouse-click. For INPUT elements whose type attribute has one of the following values: "button", "checkbox", "radio", "reset", or "submit".` - what kind of element if that with ID `load`?

Comment: if I move the spreadsheet app to backend how do I redirect page once if statement is true?

Comment: Hello @Renier, what are you trying to do exactly? Seems like you are trying to create an authentication process for a website of your own - however, this doesn't seem to be secure at all. You may want to read about web authentication [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/)...

Comment: I'm just trying to create a login system in google app script

Comment: Hey @Renier, was the answer I published useful to you? I'd love to know how you moved on with the issue you originally presented. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your Google Apps Script code and your client-side Javascript code:

### Client-side JavaScript code

```js
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", submitL); //eventlistener for login 

function submitL() {
  var loginInfo = {}
  loginInfo.email = document.getElementById.("email").value;
  loginInfo.password = document.getElementById.("password").value;

  var email = loginList.map(function (r) {
    return r[0]
  });

  var password = loginList.map(function (r) {
    return r[1]
  });

  var viewNameData = loginList.map(function (r) {
    return r[2]
  });
  var loginEmail = loginInfo.email;
  var loginPW = loginInfo.password;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onLoginResponse).logIn(loginEmail, loginPW);
}

function onLoginResponse(loggedIn) {
  if (loggedIn) {
    document.getElementById("load").click();
  } else {
    alert("Login unsuccessful, wrong credentials.");
  }
}
```

### Server-side Google Apps Script code

```js
function getLoginList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15rUIxS8w53bvPZvTKuOdGw-ZP6eWMaykVJ26vqGBkEg");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("logindet");
  return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
}

function logIn(loginEmail, loginPW) {
  var loginList = getLoginList();
  for (var i=0; i<loginList.length; i++) {
    var row = loginList[i];
    if (loginEmail == row[0] && loginPW == row[1]) {
      // Found user
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

### Explanation

SpreadsheetApp cannot be accessed from the client-side, so this separation is necessary.  In this case, the client side requests the server side to run the `logIn` function, with the `loginEmail` and `loginPW` parameters. Afterwards, it will handle the response of that remote function.

```js
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onLoginResponse).logIn(loginEmail, loginPW);
```

The remote function returns `true` in case a login match is found, and otherwise returns `false`. If the response is positive, the `document.getElementById("load").click();` sentence will be executed.

Bear in mind that this application can still be "hacked", since one can still execute that button click i.e. from the developer tools console. If you are concerned about security, I would suggest you learn about and implement other, more secure authentication methods.

### References

You can learn more about HTML Service communication (front-end and back-end) in this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication